# php and symbolic links

Tags: php, exec, symlink

I want to make a temporary copy of a file to download so I used symbolic links. It works on my localhost but when I upload it it doesn't work !! I checked the permissions of my "tmp" directory .
Here is the code :

```
$symlink = GenName($name);
$pwd = exec("pwd");
exec('ln -s "'.$pwd.'/videos/'.$name.'" "'.$pwd.'/tmp/'.$symlink.'"');
```

Any Idea how to fix it or another idea to protect original file and provide a temporary file of course not a copy ,no space !!!

Comment: You don't have to exec `ln`, PHP has a [`symlink` function](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php). Also, "it doesn't work !!" means absolutely nothing. Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: By creating a symlink you are not creating a "copy" of the file, rather a reference to the file.

Comment: @Raw Can you clarify that statement?

Comment: symlink works on Windows only , I have Linux host

Comment: @Issam Don't do that to begin with! Use a PHP script that offers the file for download, no need to symlink anything.

Comment: What, really? `symlink()` works fine on Linux - I use it my scripts all the time.

Comment: @IssamZoli: What? No. `symlink` works just fine in Linux, and in fact was not available on Windows platforms before PHP 5.3.

Comment: 5.3.0  This function is now available on Windows platforms (Vista, Server 2008 or greater).

Comment: To quote the [change log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php#refsect1-function.symlink-changelog): `5.3.0 This function is now available on Windows platforms (Vista, Server 2008 or greater).`

Comment: ...yes, it is *finally also* available on Windows since 5.3.

Comment: @IssamZoli: This means that before 5.3.0 it wasn't available on Windows. It has _always_ been available on Linux.

Comment: For the second parameter can I pass a path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trash the whole approach with symlinks! If you want to allow temporary access to a file, do it with a PHP script. Give your users a URL like `example.com/download.php?file=foobar&token=abcdef12345`, which will be handled by a script like this:

```
if (!is_valid($_GET['token']) /* your validation logic here */) {
    die('Invalid token');
}

// your content type here
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
readfile('original.pdf');
```

See [`header`](http://php.net/header) and [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile).